Android Studio's Split mode doesn't show the code
So as we all know the Split mode in Android Studio is supposed to be showing both code and previews of our composable functions (if any exist in a given file).
I managed to break it somehow, so that now the Split mode looks exactly the same as a Design mode (it shows previews only, without any code).
How do I return things back to normal? I tried to invalidate caches and restart; I also played with settings in Editor -> Design Tools - neither seems to help.
This is how it looks like if anyone's interested:


I believe you've accidentally shifted the preview pane to the left, causing it to obscure the entire editor pane.

In the split view you have a vertical divider in the middle that you can use to resize the panes: When you make one larger the other gets smaller. You probably just made the right pane (where the preview is) as large as possible so the left pane (where the code is) vanished.
The vertical divider is at the left side of the preview pane, so just pull that to the right and the code pane should resurface.
If you have some other window on the left of the code/preview window you probably need to close that first so you do not adjust that window's size instead.

This same thing just happened to me. Its hard to grad that divider when there is another divider there for the panes on the left as well.

That's why I recommended closing any windows that may be there, see the last paragraph of my answer.
